CDN setup with signed url not working on GCP
I have below shell script to create the storage bucket, load balancer and relevant CDN setup with signed url when i try to access to the link, i get error - Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /test.txt from this server.
Shell Script
#!/bin/bash

# Don't exit on error
set +e

# Function to run command and log errors
run_command() {
    if ! "$@"; then
        echo "Error executing: $*" >&2
        ERROR_LOG+="Error executing: $*\n"
    fi
}

# Function to get expiration time (works on both macOS and Linux)
get_expiration_time() {
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
        # macOS
        date -v+1H +%s
    else
        # Linux
        date -d "+1 hour" +%s
    fi
}

# Initialize error log
ERROR_LOG=""

# Get project details
PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value project)
PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID --format="value(projectNumber)")
BUCKET_NAME="test-cdn-bucket0-$PROJECT_ID"
BACKEND_NAME="test-cdn-backend0"
KEY_FILE="cdn_key.txt"
KEY_NAME="test-cdn-key"

echo "Setting up Cloud CDN for project: $PROJECT_ID"

# Create a test bucket
echo "Creating Cloud Storage bucket..."
run_command gsutil mb -p $PROJECT_ID gs://$BUCKET_NAME

# Upload a test file
echo "Uploading test file..."
echo "This is a test file for Cloud CDN" > test.txt
run_command gsutil cp test.txt gs://$BUCKET_NAME/

# Set bucket CORS configuration
echo "Setting bucket CORS configuration..."
cat > cors-config.json << EOL
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
EOL
run_command gsutil cors set cors-config.json gs://$BUCKET_NAME

# Create a backend bucket with Cloud CDN enabled
echo "Creating backend bucket with Cloud CDN enabled..."
run_command gcloud compute backend-buckets create $BACKEND_NAME --gcs-bucket-name=$BUCKET_NAME --enable-cdn

# Generate a key for signed URLs
echo "Generating key for signed URLs..."
head -c 16 /dev/urandom | base64 | tr +/ -_ > $KEY_FILE

# Add the key to the backend bucket
echo "Adding key to backend bucket..."
run_command gcloud compute backend-buckets add-signed-url-key $BACKEND_NAME --key-name=$KEY_NAME --key-file=$KEY_FILE

# Configure Cloud Storage permissions
echo "Configuring Cloud Storage permissions..."
run_command gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:service-$PROJECT_NUMBER@cloud-cdn-fill.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer gs://$BUCKET_NAME

# Set maximum cache time (optional, set to 1 hour)
echo "Setting maximum cache time..."
run_command gcloud compute backend-buckets update $BACKEND_NAME --signed-url-cache-max-age=3600

# Create a URL map
echo "Creating URL map..."
run_command gcloud compute url-maps create web-map --default-backend-bucket=$BACKEND_NAME

# Create a target HTTP proxy
echo "Creating target HTTP proxy..."
run_command gcloud compute target-http-proxies create http-lb-proxy --url-map=web-map

# Create a global forwarding rule
echo "Creating global forwarding rule..."
run_command gcloud compute forwarding-rules create http-content-rule \
    --global \
    --target-http-proxy=http-lb-proxy \
    --ports=80

# Get the IP address of the load balancer
LB_IP=$(gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe http-content-rule --global --format="value(IPAddress)")

echo "Load Balancer IP: $LB_IP"

# Construct the URL using the load balancer IP
OBJECT_NAME="test.txt"
URL="http://$LB_IP/$OBJECT_NAME"

echo "Object URL: $URL"

# Create a signed URL
echo "Creating signed URL..."
EXPIRATION=$(get_expiration_time)
SIGNED_URL=$(run_command gcloud compute sign-url "$URL" --key-name=$KEY_NAME --key-file=$KEY_FILE --expires-in=$EXPIRATION)

if [ -n "$SIGNED_URL" ]; then
    echo "Signed URL created: $SIGNED_URL"
else
    echo "Failed to create signed URL. Check the error log for details."
fi

# Remove public access
echo "Removing public access to the bucket..."
run_command gsutil acl set private gs://$BUCKET_NAME

echo "Setup completed. Errors (if any):"
echo -e $ERROR_LOG

echo "Setup complete. Please wait a few minutes for the CDN to become fully operational."
echo "Then test your signed URL in a browser or with curl:"
echo "curl -v '$SIGNED_URL'"
echo ""
echo "If you encounter access issues, try the following troubleshooting steps:"
echo "1. Verify the backend bucket is correctly associated with the URL map:"
echo "   gcloud compute url-maps describe web-map"
echo "2. Check the Cloud Storage bucket permissions:"
echo "   gsutil iam get gs://$BUCKET_NAME"
echo "3. Ensure the signed URL is generated correctly by comparing its format with the documentation"
echo "4. Test accessing the object directly from Cloud Storage to isolate CDN issues:"
echo "   gsutil signurl -d 1h $KEY_FILE gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$OBJECT_NAME"
echo ""
echo "IMPORTANT: Ensure that your origin (Cloud Storage) is configured to validate signatures on every signed request."
echo "SECURITY REMINDER: Regularly rotate your signing keys for better security."

below is the access information on the storage bucket
Location : us (multiple regions in United States)
Storage class : Standard
Public access : Not public
Protection : Soft Delete

